# Set property names to each item in List c#

Tags: c#, list, properties

How can i set property names to each value of my List?

this is my List and my "foreach" for it

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

foreach (var item in db.Pos)
{
     list.Add(item.Description);
     list.Add(item.Pdv);
     list.Add(item.Rid);
     list.Add(total);       
}
```

how can i give it a property name to each value like: Property `Description = list.Add(item.Description)`

Comment: Consider adding reason why you want to do that. Otherwise some "creative" solution with expressions may be needed (or even more complicated) because values have no source associated with them.

Comment: Maybe you need to use Dictionary<key,value> collection instead of List?

Comment: Arturo Martinez, why do you believe VBA tag (listobject) is so important to this C# question so you decided to add it back?

Comment: im trying to serialize my list but the result jsonstring i need it with its property names not just the values thats why im trying to set the list its properties before serializing

Comment: Will you JSON always create a similar object with the same properties?  Consider pasting you code into something like http://json2csharp.com/ and creating a class or struct based on the JSON. Then, you can easily deserialize into the data object.

Comment: Serializing a generic Dictionary to a JSON object should result in JSON with named properties equal to the keys of the source Dictionary...

Comment: My json creates the serealization just fine but i need to make some code and add columns before serializing so i added the data to a list and modify the code in the list and then tryed to serialize the list but i need its properties defined to work

Answer (score 2):

Given you have a collection of objects by `db.Pos`, maybe a list of dictionaries can help you, for sample:

```
var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (var item in db.Pos)
{
     var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     dic.Add("Description", item.Descripcion);
     dic.Add("Pdv", item.Pdv);
     dic.Add("Rid", item.Rid);
     dic.Add("Total", total);       

     list.Add(dic);
}
```

Then you can try to read a property:

```
var description = list[0]["Description"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your clarification that you'd like to serialize your data to JSON, consider using an anonymous type:

```
var items = db.Pos.Select(item => new
{
    Description = item.Description,
    Pvd = item.Pvd,
    Rid = item.Rid,
    Total = total
});
```

*NOTE: It's not clear to me where the variable "total" gets defined...*

This should serialize nicely into an array of objects for you.

Comment: i reduce the foreach loop to make it more easy to understand, but i need my list to have properties of their own since my list wil have more columns than my Json, thats why i want to add prperty to each item in list and then serialize it

Comment: So then it's not very apparent what your goal is. If you've somehow modified your code to try to "simplify" your question, you've just made it that much harder to understand your task. The code as you post it will generate a narrow array of a series of items all stacked on top of one another. Is this what you want?